# Limit objects in array based on property value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like the one shown below. I need to limit the number of objects in the array with `ord:1` to 5. How can I to limit the number of objects inside an array based on `ord` property?

```
[{"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-0","label":"Spigen Samsung GS5 
  Case","model":{"ord":1,"short_description":"Samsung Galaxy S5"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-1","label":"Spigen iPhone 5/5s 
  Case","model":{"ord":1,"short_description":"iPhone 5 and 5s"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-2","label":"Earphones","model": 
  {"ord":1,"short_description":"Buy earphones"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-5","label":"Web Conferencing","model": 
  {"ord":1,"short_description":"Request"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-6","label":"Dreamweaver","model": 
  {"ord":1,"short_description":null}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-7","label":"SSL Certification","model": 
  {"ord":1,"short_description":"Do you need to update"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-8","label":"Access","model": 
  {"ord":1,"short_description":"Microsoft Access"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-9","label":"Fireworks","model": 
  {"ord":1,"short_description":"Adobe Systems Fireworks"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-10","label":"Spigen iPhone 6 Case","model": 
  {"ord":1,"short_description":"For iPhone 6"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-11","label":"What is a cookie? 
  \t\t","model":{"ord":4,"short_description":"What is a cookie?\t\t"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-12","label":"What are phishing scams and 
  how can I avoid them?\n\t\t","model":{"ord":4,"short_description":"What 
  are phishing"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-13","label":"How to Deal with 
  Spam","model":{"ord":4,"short_description":"How to Deal with Spam"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-14","label":"What is Spam?","model": 
  {"ord":4,"short_description":"What is Spam?}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-15","label":"How to set\n\t\t","model": 
  {"ord":4,"short_description":"How\n\t\t"}}
```

]

Comment: What do you mean *limit*? Prevent addition of? Reduce from too many? Warn about?

Comment: @isherwood I'll create new array out of this and in the result array i need olly 5 objects with ord:1

Comment: Still not clear. You could help people out by formatting the above so it's readable using an online JSON formatter. You could also include an example of the expected results.

Comment: Your script is invalid, it contains unterminated strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dictionary with `ord` values as keys and store there up to 5 items.
In the end just concat all arrays in dictionary.

```js
let input = [{
      "id": "typeahead-86-4951-option-0",
      "label": "Spigen Samsung GS5 Case",
      "model": {
        "ord": 1,
        "short_description": "Samsung Galaxy S5"
      }
    }, {
      "id": "typeahead-86-4951-option-1",
      "label": "Spigen iPhone 5/5s Case",
      "model": {
        "ord": 1,
        "short_description": "iPhone 5 and 5s"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "typeahead-86-4951-option-2",
      "label": "Earphones",
      "model": {
        "ord": 1,
        "short_description": "Buy earphones"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "typeahead-86-4951-option-5",
      "label": "Web Conferencing",
      "model": {
        "ord": 1,
        "short_description": "Request"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "typeahead-86-4951-option-6",
      "label": "Dreamweaver",
      "model": {
        "ord": 1,
        "short_description": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "typeahead-86-4951-option-7",
      "label": "SSL Certification",
      "model": {
        "ord": 1,
        "short_description": "Do you need to update"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "typeahead-86-4951-option-8",
      "label": "Access",
      "model": {
        "ord": 1,
        "short_description": "Microsoft Access"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "typeahead-86-4951-option-9",
      "label": "Fireworks",
      "model": {
        "ord": 1,
        "short_description": "Adobe Systems Fireworks"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "typeahead-86-4951-option-10",
      "label": "Spigen iPhone 6 Case",
      "model": {
        "ord": 1,
        "short_description": "For iPhone 6"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "typeahead-86-4951-option-11",
      "label": "What is a cookie?\t\t",
      "model": {
        "ord": 4,
        "short_description": "What is a cookie?\t\t"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "typeahead-86-4951-option-12",
      "label": "What are phishing scams and how can I avoid them?\n\t\t",
      "model": {
        "ord": 4,
        "short_description": "What are phishing"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "typeahead-86-4951-option-13",
      "label": "How to Deal with Spam",
      "model": {
        "ord": 4,
        "short_description": "How to Deal with Spam"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "typeahead-86-4951-option-14",
      "label": "What is Spam?",
      "model": {
        "ord": 4,
        "short_description": "What is Spam?"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "typeahead-86-4951-option-15",
      "label": "How to set\n\t\t",
      "model": {
        "ord": 4,
        "short_description": "How\n\t\t"
      }
    }
  ],
  ordObj;

ordObj = input.reduce(function(acc, el) {
  let ord = el.model.ord;
  if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(ord)) {
    acc[ord] = [];
  }
  if (acc[ord].length < 5) {
    acc[ord].push(el);
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

let result = Object.values(ordObj).reduce((acc, el) => (acc.concat(el)), []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a small loop like this, counting how many `"ord":1` you keep, and stopping after 5 :

```js
let input = [
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-0","label":"Spigen Samsung GS5 Case","model":{"ord":1,"short_description":"Samsung Galaxy S5"}}, {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-1","label":"Spigen iPhone 5/5s Case","model":{"ord":1,"short_description":"iPhone 5 and 5s"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-2","label":"Earphones","model": {"ord":1,"short_description":"Buy earphones"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-5","label":"Web Conferencing","model": {"ord":1,"short_description":"Request"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-6","label":"Dreamweaver","model": {"ord":1,"short_description":null}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-7","label":"SSL Certification","model":{"ord":1,"short_description":"Do you need to update"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-8","label":"Access","model": {"ord":1,"short_description":"Microsoft Access"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-9","label":"Fireworks","model": {"ord":1,"short_description":"Adobe Systems Fireworks"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-10","label":"Spigen iPhone 6 Case","model": {"ord":1,"short_description":"For iPhone 6"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-11","label":"What is a cookie?\t\t","model":{"ord":4,"short_description":"What is a cookie?\t\t"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-12","label":"What are phishing scams and how can I avoid them?\n\t\t","model": {"ord":4,"short_description":"What are phishing"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-13","label":"How to Deal with Spam","model":{"ord":4,"short_description":"How to Deal with Spam"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-14","label":"What is Spam?","model": {"ord":4,"short_description":"What is Spam?"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-15","label":"How to set\n\t\t","model": {"ord":4,"short_description":"How\n\t\t"}}
],
 output = [],
 count = 0;
   
input.forEach( obj => {
  if(obj.model.ord===1){
    if(count>=5) return
    count++
  }
 output.push(obj)
})

console.log("Count before : " + input.filter(o=>o.model.ord===1).length )
console.log("Count after : " + output.filter(o=>o.model.ord===1).length )
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use filter methos to filter out order:1 records and slice array methods to get first 5

```
let final = arr.filter(v => v.model.ord === 1).slice(0, 5);
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NOmXar?editors=1010

```js
let arr = [{"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-0","label":"Spigen Samsung GS5 Case","model":{"ord":1,"short_description":"Samsung Galaxy S5"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-1","label":"Spigen iPhone 5/5s Case","model":{"ord":1,"short_description":"iPhone 5 and 5s"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-2","label":"Earphones","model": 
  {"ord":1,"short_description":"Buy earphones"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-5","label":"Web Conferencing","model": 
  {"ord":1,"short_description":"Request"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-6","label":"Dreamweaver","model": 
  {"ord":1,"short_description":null}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-7","label":"SSL Certification","model": 
  {"ord":1,"short_description":"Do you need to update"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-8","label":"Access","model": 
  {"ord":1,"short_description":"Microsoft Access"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-9","label":"Fireworks","model": 
  {"ord":1,"short_description":"Adobe Systems Fireworks"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-10","label":"Spigen iPhone 6 Case","model": 
  {"ord":1,"short_description":"For iPhone 6"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-11","label":"What is a cookie? \t\t","model":{"ord":4,"short_description":"What is a cookie?\t\t"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-12","label":"What are phishing scams and how can I avoid them?\n\t\t","model":{"ord":4,"short_description":"What are phishing"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-13","label":"How to Deal with Spam","model":{"ord":4,"short_description":"How to Deal with Spam"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-14","label":"What is Spam?","model": {"ord":4,"short_description":"What is Spam?"}},
 {"id":"typeahead-86-4951-option-15","label":"How to set\n\t\t","model": {"ord":4,"short_description":"How\n\t\t"}}]
  

let final = arr.filter(v => v.model.ord === 1).slice(0, 5);

console.log(final)
```

Comment: Not all objects inside the array contain `"ord":1`. You're removing a lot of stuff that OP wants to keep.

Answer (score 0):

You can create something similar to what I below as `tracker`. Use that variable to keep a count of items by `ord`. In my example below, I am using `Array.prototype.filter` on your original array of data below. Each time the callback encounters an array element with an `ord` property equal to five, the `tracker` count is incremented. If the count is less than 5 we can add it to our new array, if not, skip it.

```js
var tracker = (function(i) {
  var c = i;
  return {
    value: () => c,
    increment: () => c += 1,
    decrement: () => c -= 1
  }
})(0);
var data = [{
  id: 'item0',
  ord: 1
}, {
  id: 'item1',
  ord: 1
}, {
  id: 'item2',
  ord: 1
}, {
  id: 'item3',
  ord: 1
}, {
  id: 'item4',
  ord: 1
}, {
  id: 'item5',
  ord: 1
}, {
  id: 'item6',
  ord: 1
}, {
  id: 'item7',
  ord: 1
}, {
  id: 'item8',
  ord: 1
}, {
  id: 'item9',
  ord: 2
}, {
  id: 'item10',
  ord: 2
}, {
  id: 'item11',
  ord: 2
}, {
  id: 'item12',
  ord: 2
}];
var limited = data.filter(el => {
  if (el.ord === 1) {
    tracker.increment();
    if (tracker.value() < 6) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});
console.log(limited);
```